# Postfix smtpd won't talk to saslauthd

Tags: debian, postfix, pam, smtp-auth, saslauthd

I have an saslauthd setup to authenticate against PAM. It seems to do its stuff:

```
root@sasltest:~# testsaslauthd -u quest -p #### -s smtp
0: OK "Success."
```

I have libsasl 2.1.23, postfix 2.7.1.

I have a postfix configured thus:

```
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
smtpd_sasl_path = /var/spool/postfix/private/saslauthd/mux
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

With a master.cf thus:

```
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

However, trying to authenticate in this postfix gives the following error message:

```
Jan 23 22:13:14 sasltest postfix/smtpd[1252]: warning: SASL authentication problem: unable to open Berkeley db /etc/sasldb2: No such file or directory
Jan 23 22:13:14 sasltest postfix/smtpd[1252]: warning: SASL authentication problem: unable to open Berkeley db /etc/sasldb2: No such file or directory
Jan 23 22:13:14 sasltest postfix/smtpd[1252]: warning: X[A.B.C.D]: SASL LOGIN
```

authentication failed: authentication failure

Meanwhile, there is no output from my debug-logging saslauthd.

I interpret this as meaning that libsasl2 tries to uses sasldb auth rather than try to talk to saslauthd. What I can't figure out how to tell libsasl that I want it to talk to saslauthd.

Various instructions inform you to create a file /etc/sasl2/smtpd.conf or /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf. I have tried creating these files containing:

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: LOGIN PLAIN
```

But to no effect.

How do I instruct libsasl to use saslauthd authentication?

(I can of course create /var/spool/postfix/etc/sasldb2, but this will still not result in connections to saslauthd.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [cyrus-sasl mailing list post](http://lists.andrew.cmu.edu/pipermail/cyrus-sasl/2008-July/001487.html) eventually set me on the right path.

For posterity, an attempt to produce reasonably explicit config. /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
cyrus_sasl_config_path = /etc/postfix/sasl
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

The trick in above conf is that postfix+libsasl2 does this: ${cyrus_sasl_config_path}/${smtpd_sasl_path}.conf

Once we have gotten that far, in /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf we can tell libsasl that we wanna talk to saslauthd:

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: LOGIN PLAIN
saslauthd_path: private/saslauthd/mux
```

Since smtpd is chrooted, saslauthd_path is relative to /var/spool/postfix. I use bind mounting to get /var/run/saslauthd into private.

Answer (score 3):

Stumbling over similar issue in Ubuntu 20.04. There, the `cyrus_sasl_config_path` parameter to postfix isn't recognized at all. It's looking up **/etc/postfix/sasl2/** for containing the **smtpd.conf** instead.

In Ubuntu 20.04 smtpd seems to be chrooted by default. However, its chroot preparation script in **/usr/lib/postfix/configure-instance.sh** isn't covering any SASL-related files, thus you have to put it into chroot manually.

1. Create the missing folder in chroot:

   ```
   mkdir -p /var/spool/postfix/etc/postfix/sasl2
   ```
2. Create the SASL2 configuration file there:

   ```
   cat >>/var/spool/postfix/etc/postfix/sasl2/smtpd.conf <<EOT
   pwcheck_method: saslauthd
   mech_list: LOGIN PLAIN
   EOT
   ```
3. Link it from related global folder:

   ```
   mkdir -p /etc/postfix/sasl2
   ln -s /var/spool/postfix/etc/postfix/sasl2/smtpd.conf /etc/postfix/sasl2/smtpd.conf
   ```
4. Make sure saslauthd socket is available in folder **/var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/**. You can control this by adjusting file **/etc/default/saslauthd**. See the comments found in that file.

Comment: This is a much better answer than turning off chroot on smtpd because doing that is a recipe for getting hacked.  And it fixes the problem.  People who don't understand how chroot works should not be trusted to set up a mail server.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for about an hour before figuring out via `strace -f -p pid`ing the running postfix process that it couldn't find my `sasldb2` file because it was putting itself in a `chroot`.

Edit `/etc/postfix/master.cf` and put an `n` in the `chroot` column.  Restart postfix.  Should work now.